# Host name MYDOMAIN doesn't match any name found on the server certificate CN=MyServer

Tags: exchange

I recently upgraded (i.e., rebuilt from the ground up) my home server. It now had Windows Server 2016 and Exchange Server 2016 running on it. I imported the entire PST from my old e-mail account on the old server. I'm trying to get things connecting to Exchange such as Outlook and Touchdown HD on my phone. I'm using https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com to do some initial testing. I'm getting the error (among others):

```
Host name MYDOMAIN doesn't match any name found on the server certificate CN=MyServer
```

I created a self-signed certificate and installed it on the server. Did I create the certificate incorrectly? If I can provide more information, please tell me what.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: Yes you created your cert wrong.  The CN value should be the name fqdn you use to access the server.   Possibly with 'subject alternative names' set as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you created a self signed certificate, you will always get errors, because that isn't trusted. You need to use a trusted certificate for the most reliable connection to Exchange. There are free and non-free options for that - but don't use a self signed.

You will also need to adjust Exchange to use the public name of the server both internally and externally via split DNS. The server's real isn't used in my scenarios. I have instructions here: http://semb.ee/hostnames2013

Answer (score 0):

To use self-signed certificate or PKI certificate issued by internal CA, we need to install this certificate on client manually, otherwise we will get a certificate warning. Also, the self-signed certificate is not supported by Outlook Anywhere or the offline address book, thus we need a PKI certificate or 3rd trusted certificate (it's recommend in a product environment).

Moreover, we recommend to deploy split DNS instead of adding server FQDN in certificate. Thus, try the suggestion as Sembee mentioned above.